QGIS .tif file completely black/greyed out
When I open a .tif file in QGIS, it is completely grey.
I'm completely new to this discipline, perhaps a simple fix, but I've Google'd it, and am at a loss.
Grey Box

USGS Download

I can see that there is no gradient band displayed under the icon on the left where I drag-&-dropped the file, why is that?
